# Kinvi3D 1.2 Start Up Issue/ Alterrnative for text input with Kinect?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

I was planning to use the Kinvi3D v1.2 from [here](http://www.kinvi3d.net/wp/). However, upon starting up the program, I get the error "failed to detect a kinect sensor." I am using a Windows 8 64-bit machine with Microsoft Kinect SDK. Has anyone encountered this error that was able to get it to work and how? The website only provides the latest version and no access to the older ones. I wanted to use Kinvi3d because it allows the user to use the 8pen keyboard for text input. Are there any other alternatives to Kinvi3d for text input while navigating the web for example?

Comment: Kinvi v1.2 is quite old, I think at least 1-2 years old.  
So it might still depending on OpenNI v1 driver or Kinect SDK older version.  
You might want to find the appropriate driver and the correct version for it.

Comment: thank you, thats a great point